# How can I construct a MySQL query to select posts with specific associated information?

Tags: sql, mysql

I am working with three tables in my MySQL database, and I need some help constructing a SELECT query.

The structure of my tables is as follows:

1. `posts` table: `(postId, userId, post)`
2. `likes` table: `(userId, postId)`
3. `users` table: `(userId, email, password)`

In the `likes` table, if a user with `userId` = `1` liked a post with `postId` = `'abc'`, there will be a record `(1, 'abc')`.

Now, I want to create a query that selects posts and returns the following columns:

1. `posts.postId`
2. `posts.userId`
3. `posts.post`
4. `users.email` (This should be the email of the author of the post)
5. `likes_count` (This should be the count of likes for the post)
6. `isLiked` (This should be `true` if a specified user has liked the
   post, and `false` otherwise. I will pass the `userId` for this
   condition)

Could anyone provide me with the SQL query that would accomplish this? I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: Please put more effort in your question. Provide some sample data, show the expected result (both as tables), explain what you have tried, explain what went wrong. SO is no coding service.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the following `SQL` query to retrieve the desired information:

```
SELECT 
    p.postId,
    p.userId,
    p.post,
    u.email AS author_email,
    likes.likes_count,
    CASE WHEN likes.userId IS NOT NULL THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END AS isLiked
FROM 
    posts p
    INNER JOIN users u ON p.userId = u.userId
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
            postId,
            COUNT(*) AS likes_count,
            MAX(CASE WHEN userId = <user_id> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS userId
        FROM 
            likes
        GROUP BY 
            postId
    ) likes ON p.postId = likes.postId
```

Make sure to replace <`user_id`> with the **actual user ID** for which you want to check the liked status.

Comment: It almost works. But when a post has multiple likes, isLiked isn't working correctly. See the first 2 rows of the below image.
`https://i.postimg.cc/rs3dZSGr/image.png`

Comment: I've edited my answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT 
    Posts.postId,
    Posts.userId,
    Posts.post,
    Author.email AS author_email,
    COUNT(likes.userid) as likes_count ,
    MAX(CASE WHEN likes.userid = <userid> THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END) as IsLiked
FROM Posts

inner join Users as Author ON Author.userid=Posts.userid
LEFT join likes On likes.Postid=Posts.postId

group by Posts.postId,
        Posts.userId,
        Posts.post,
        Author.email
```